How can I resize the gif to fit into the Tkinter window?
This is my code:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from itertools import count, cycle
class ImageLabel(tk.Label):

    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        frames = []
        try:
            for i in count(1):
                
                frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
                im.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            pass
        self.frames = cycle(frames)
        try:
            self.delay = im.info['duration']
        except:
            self.delay = 100
        if len(frames) == 1:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
        else:
            self.next_frame()
    def unload(self):
        self.config(image=None)
        self.frames = None
    def next_frame(self):
        if self.frames:
            self.config(image=next(self.frames))
            self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)
#demo :
root = tk.Tk()
lbl = ImageLabel(root)
lbl.pack()
lbl.load('bg.gif')
root.mainloop()

The gif file does play though when you full size the tkinter screen you can see the gif is way smaller the screen. Is there anyway I can debug the code to make it resize to the screen?
This is what I tried:
            for i in count(1):
            resized = im.resize((800, 600), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy()))
            im.seek(i)

This code also works, but does not actively resize to the Tkinter screen.
I also tried this:
            for i in count(1):
            resized = im.resize((root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized.copy()))
            im.seek(i)

But it shows a blank screen...

Post what you have tried on resizing the images.

There are many answers to your question on SO. Try using SO search by entering the follow search pattern. [tkinter] resizing image pil

@acw1668 i made a variable called resized which did resize the image but not to the screen.

@chinenye As said, you need to post what you have tried on resizing the images, otherwise it is hard to identify why it does not work for you.

@acw1668 to make it more clear here is the code I tried:

You need to call im.copy().resize(...) instead of im.resize(...).

@acw1668 it still shows a white screen.

Post the [mre] using im.copy().resize(...). It works for me.

@acw1668 still shows a blank screen and I'm not sure why

Did you print out the target size, i.e. print(root.winfo_width(), root.winfo_height()) to see whether it is what you expect?
